# Bootstrap Scrollspy highlighting first navbar item on load

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building a single page site using bootstrap and have set the navbar up, but it doesn't include a 'home' link as this falls to the logo.

I have named the 'home' element and all further sections accordingly and implemented scrollspy. BUt when the page first loads in the first navbar link is highlighted (which in fact is the section section within the page). When scrolling manually or using the links in the navbar scrollspy works as expected and even when clicking the logo to return to the top of the page, all links are no longer highlighted, which is the desired effect. However, whenever I first load the page, the first link is always correctly highlighted.

I've searched around and seen many posts about the last item being highlighted when using scrollspy, but never the first.

Thank you in advance. Please see attached photos to better describe the issue.

Initial Load: - Not desired

[image: Initial Load]

Navigation: - Working as expected

[image: Navigate]

Navigating back to top: - Works as expected, however this is what I expect the initial load to look like

[image: Return]

Comment: Please add your code so we can pinpoint what is going on with it , a jsfiddle or code pen would be easier to thinker with.

Comment: Odd. Not doing it on codepen...

Comment: Is it not behaving the same way on codepen ?, or it is odd to you and you are not creating a codepen . If it's the first, check for custom classes, or maybe a css you are importing directly from your machine that codepen is not taking into cosideration.

Comment: Yeah, can't replicate the issue on Codepen. Have just published to a test area on our site and it doesn't work so something odd is happening somewhere.